# Azure Geo-replicated Storage to Allow Write in Secondary Region

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, replication

Using RA-GRS Azure Storage Account, is it possible to write to a blob path in both regions?

We have two regions running the same data flows active-active (configured via Traffic Manager), however one legacy application used for file transfer to our on premise estate will only be available in the primary region. In case of DR we will manually stand up the application in the secondary region. (This is due to a limitation in the application itself.)

So the storage needs to be written to in both regions, but only in the primary region we will read (and delete on success) the data. Does RA-GRS allow this? Some delay in the files being synced to primary region will not be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Storage Account RA-GRS does not offer two-way synchronization, you would need to implement a solution yourself. azcopy offers [some functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy) for doing this.